# Slow packet transfer using bonjour and nsnetservice

Tags: ios, tcp, bluetooth

I'm working on a local network based game. By this I mean that you can play it on different iphone on local network wifi or bluetooth. I did the implementation with NSStream with a tcp connection to transfer data. I have one server who listens the network :

```
 service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local."// 4
                                              type:CreateNSString(serviceType)
                                              name:CreateNSString(serviceName)
                                              port:80];
        if(service)
        {
            service.includesPeerToPeer = YES;

            [service setDelegate:delegatePublisherObject];// 5
            [service publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections];
```

And clients who search for game sessions around :

```
serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
        serviceBrowser.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
        [serviceBrowser setDelegate:delegateBrowserObject];

        [serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType: CreateNSString(service) inDomain:@"local"];
```

But i have an issue with the data transfer between them. What i did from now, is :

i queued the data i want to send. If i can write it directly in the output stream i do

```
dataWriteQueue insertObject:data atIndex:0];
if (flag_canSendDirectly)
    [self _sendData];

...

 - (void)_sendData {
 NSData *data = [dataWriteQueue lastObject];
flag_canSendDirectly = NO;
if (data == nil)
{
    flag_canSendDirectly = YES;
    return;
}
bufferToSend = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];
NSInteger bytesWritten;

bytesWritten = [_outputStream write:bufferToSend maxLength:dataBufferLimit - currentDataOffset];
```

if the callback NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable is called i send the last pieces of data queued.

```
case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
        if (stream == _outputStream)
        {
            //read a new chunk of data
            [self _sendData];

        }

    } break;
```

I have stopped the browsing of devices when i transfer data between peers. 
The transfer is done well. But my issue here is that the transfer is pretty fast in bluetooth. But slower in wifi. I don't understand this, it doesn't seems logical. Do you have any clues about this issue ? The browsing is shut down when the peers are connected.

Comment: I can into the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately we found any solutions to this issue. The problem of slow packet transfer appears even on the apple code sample Witap, i did an udp version of this code sample but the number of packet lost is too big. The weird thing is that on bluetooth connection the data transfer is fast.